# Replace double quote .Replace string "<?xml with <?xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This is my `XML` file I am creating by code. I want to replace the starting quote with nothing or empty.

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: can you show the code for creating the xml file?

Comment: did you try regex replace using this? Regex reg = new Regex("^\"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XmlWriterSettings and set the OmitXml declarations to true:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings ();
settings.Indent = true ;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true ;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true ;

writer = XmlWriter.Create (Console.Out, settings);

writer.WriteStartElement ( "order" );
writer.WriteAttributeString ( "orderID" , "367A54" );
writer.WriteAttributeString ( "date" , "2001-05-03" );
writer.WriteElementString ( "price" , "19.95" );
writer.WriteEndElement ();

writer.Flush ();
```

Will generate:

```
  <order
    orderID = "367A54"
    date = "2001-05-03">
    <price> 19.95 </price>
  </order>
```